# how to parse a csv string containing quotations and missing values?

Tags: node.js, regex

I am trying to parse a String of comma delimited values using regex in nodejs. My string can contain extra commas inside the quotations and can have missing values. I want to ignore the commas inside the quotation and consider the missing values!

corner case: `"red, blue,,, yellow, '1,345',"`

Answer:`red blue null null yellow 1,345 null`

I am using this pieace of code:

```
str.match(/('[^']+'|[^,]+)/g)
```

the problem is it ignores the missing values. How can I fix it?

Comment: Use a CSV parser to parse CSV files. Two popular options: https://www.papaparse.com/ or https://github.com/gkindel/csv-js. Don't use regular expressions.

Comment: @Tomalak this works very well. I am just curious is there any way to ignore those rows which are not part of the CSV data in my file? I know I can ignore those lines that are comments but in my case there are some other lines in my file which are not actually in CSV format and I don't want to be part of the parsed data. I can use other functions to remove those lines before pass it to the papaparse, but it would be good if papa can take care of those junk lines itself.

Comment: You could try streaming the file: https://www.papaparse.com/faq#streaming - This parses the file line-wise, so you can react to each individual result, be it a success (valid csv data) or an error (junk line).

Answer (score 0):

```
((?<=\"|\s|,)(?:[\w])*|(?<=')[,\w]*(?='))(?='\s*,|,|\")
```

This seems workable for the output. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/23/)